# draggableColumns DataGrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, flex4.5

I am migrating my **Flex 3.2** to **FLex 4.5**.

the property `draggableColumns` of `<mx:DataGrid>` is obsolete in the `<s:DataGrid>`.

Have you an idea to have its equivalent in Flex 4.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have used that property than you just remove that because in FLEX 4.6 it automatically gives the functionality to drag the columns.

For more information Please visit this [Link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS0ab2a460655f2dc3-427f401412c60d04dca-8000.html).

Have a Nice Day.....

Comment: There is a note saying **Note:** You can only sort the columns of the DataGrid programmatically by sorting the IList passed to the columns property. That is, **you cannot use the mouse to drag a column to rearrange the columns.**